# Converting .crt to .pem using OpenSSL API

Tags: c, api, openssl, pem, crt

Can anyone show me how to convert .crt files to .pem files using the openssl API?
I tried it like this:

```
FILE *fl = fopen(cert_filestr, "r");
fseek(fl, 0, SEEK_END);
long len = ftell(fl);
char *ret = malloc(len);
fseek(fl, 0, SEEK_SET);
fread(ret, 1, len, fl);
fclose(fl);
BIO* input = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)ret, sizeof(ret));
x509 = d2i_X509_bio(input, NULL);
FILE* fd = fopen(certificateFile, "w+");
BIO* output = BIO_new_fp(fd, BIO_NOCLOSE);
X509_print_ex(output, x509, XN_FLAG_COMPAT, X509_FLAG_COMPAT);
fclose(fd);
```

But that doesn't work, x509 is always NULL.

Comment: A major problem is that using `sizeof` on a pointer gives you the size *of the pointer* and not what it points to.

Comment: Also, in C you don't have to cast a pointer to `void*`, all pointers can implicitly be casted to (and from) `void*`.

Comment: oh no, so is 'char **size = malloc(sizeof(fl));' a posibility to get the right size?

Comment: The size if `len`, it's the size you need to pass to `BIO_new_mem_buf`.

Comment: ok thank you! fixed that! but the issue still exists..

Comment: Is your .crt file der encoded or pem encoded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.crt certificate "may be encoded as binary DER or as ASCII PEM." (see http://info.ssl.com/article.aspx?id=12149).

If your .crt file is already PEM encoded you don't need to convert it, just change the file name from .crt to .pem.

If it is encoded as DER, convert it to PEM like in this example:

```
X509* x509 = NULL;
FILE* fd = NULL,*fl = NULL;

fl = fopen(cert_filestr,"rb");
if(fl) 
{
    fd = fopen(certificateFile,"w+");
    if(fd) 
    {
        x509 = d2i_X509_fp(fl,NULL);
        if(x509) 
        {
            PEM_write_X509(fd,x509);
        }
        else 
        {
           printf("failed to parse to X509 from fl");
        }
        fclose(fd);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("can't open fd");
    }
   fclose(fl);
}
else 
{
    printf("can't open f");
}
```